# Getting a view in lotus notes out of data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

So I learned how to write data to a MySQL-database and how to read from it, too, using ODBC and in one case Lotus Script using ADODB, in the other case Formula Language using @DbLookup.

So since I try to get away from our huge mass of Lotus Notes Databases my first goal would be to get all this information into a MySQL, so I can work through the databases more slowly to not create a huge cut. But of course we also need views. So is there a way to create a view in Lotus Notes that uses data from a MySQL-Database? Or would I have to still store the data in Notes and additionally in the MySQL-Database to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [feature like that for DB2](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_8.5.3/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_DB2_QUERY_VIEWS_1555_OVER.html), but not for MySQL or any other database.

The best you can do is use synchronization tools like [IBM Enterprise Integrator for Domino](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/ibm-enterprise-integrator-for-domino) or one of the many available third-party alternatives.

Comment: IEI has a feature called "Virtual documents."  I've not used it with MySQL, but with DB2 and SQL it is very slick.  In Notes you have a document with a field with the key information, and the IEI activity fills in all the rest of the data so that it looks like it's stored in Notes but isn't.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not possible without duplicating the data from MySQL as Notes documents.